# How would I go about building this bed frame myself?

Tags: wooden-furniture, bedroom, frame

I am in love with this simplistic style bed, however, it is quite expensive. I feel like if I had the right instructions or some ideas to go on I could do it myself. If anyone has any idea on how this bed was built please help!

here is the link for a larger picture 
http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=30073654&parentid=A_FURN_FURNITURE_BED

these are the dimensions 
SIZE
Queen
- Length: 81"
- Width: 61"
- Height: 13"

[image]

[image]

Comment: any change you have a larger picture? Without knowing more, odd are you build that like you would a table, albeit with a possible center support and a slatted top rather than solid. FYI, an easy way to implement the slats is to buy the slats from Ikea.

Comment: thanks @DA01 and this link is the only larger pictures available http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=30073654&parentid=A_FURN_FURNITURE_BED

Comment: Looks like the legs are 2.25" at the top, and narrow down to about 1.25" round where they meet the floor. I'd be concerned with floor gouging if the bed is meant for two people.

Comment: There may be hidden custom hardware in the example, but using standard carpentry joints will serve you well. Like any table structure, the legs must be very rigidly connected. Use mortise and tenon or substantial pocket screws. Consider a couple extra legs setback from the edge under the center beam to reduce structural requirements.

Comment: That bed frame is made of mango wood. I just searched the web for mango veneer and mango wood: couldn't find any veneer, and the wood is real hard to find, and expensive. My thought: save your money and buy it from the linked site.  Alternately, find another wood to use that can be bought as veneer. Veneering is cheaper than solid wood, but looks the same.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to make that bed for less than $800 without already having the tools. If you can get access to tools for cheap (via tool library or sharing), then its more possible. By tools I mean a jointer, planer, band saw, drill, table saw, and measuring tools. That's what you'd need to go from rough lumber to dimensioned pieces joined with mortise and tenon. Hand tools are cheaper but they need a lot more time and skill. Mattias Wandel has a good video on building a bed. It should give you an idea of what's involved. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JY1mxnXCeF8.